# Windows batch label loop

Tags: loops, batch-file, if-statement

Having a hard time running my batch file.
I believe it has something to do with my if statements, it doesn't fall through.
I always end up with "if was unexpected at this time".
Please any help is grateful

```
:firstNumber
set /p "firstNum = Enter the first number (other than 22) "
if "%firstNum%"=="22" (
goto :end
) else (
goto :secondNumber
)

:secondNumber
set /p "secondNum = Enter the second number (other than 22 and 0) "
if "%secondNum%"=="22" (
goto :end
)   if "%secondNum%"=="0" (
goto :errorNumber
) else (
goto :command
)

:errorNumber
echo You cannot divide by 0
goto :secondNumber

:command
set /a quotient=%firstNum% / %secondNum% 
echo "%firstNum% divided by %secondNum% = !quotient!

:end
```

Comment: I would insert a standard `set` command before `set /P` in order to define a default in case the user simply presses _enter_, like `set "firstNum=0"` and `set "secondNum=0"`, respectively; then I would remove the quotes from the `if` comparisons and replace the operator `==` by `EQU` in order to do numeric comparisons rather than string comparisons (like `if %secondNum% EQU 0`); finally I would indent all commands present within a pair of parentheses to improve readability...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
)   if "%secondNum%"=="0" (
```

should be

```
)
if "%secondNum%"=="0" (
```

The `)` terminates the previous `if` statement. `cmd` sees the rest of the line as something that shouldn't follow `)`

---

(later - missing operand...)

Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

Hence, your `set /p "firstnum = ...` sets a variable called "firstNum<kbd>Space</kbd>" - and this is not the same as the variable "firstNum"

Since neither `firstnum` nor `secondnum` contain values, `cmd` sees

> set /a quotient= /

Lose the spaces on both sides of the `=` in your `set` statements.

Comment: after i made the change the error I am now receiving is "missing operand  divided by = "